# Preventing the "Do you want to save the changes" dialog in a macOS app in Swift

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument

In a document based macOS project I would like to avoid the

"Do you want to save the changes you made in the document “Untitled”? "Your changes will be lost if you don’t save them."

message.

I'm traying to implement this solution [Preventing the "Save on Exit" dialogue on exit of a Cocoa Document Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058358/preventing-the-save-on-exit-dialogue-on-exit-of-a-cocoa-document-application)

```
import Cocoa

    class Document: NSDocument {

        var myDoc = MyDoc()

        func isDocumentEdited() -> Bool {
            return false
        }

    }
```

but I get the error:

> Method 'isDocumentEdited()' with Objective-C selector
>   'isDocumentEdited' conflicts with getter for 'documentEdited' from
>   superclass 'NSDocument' with the same Objective-C selector

What could I do to resolve this error?

Comment: If you also don't want the dirty dot, override `updateChangeCount(_:)` instead of `isDocumentEdited` and do nothing;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are calling `isDocumentEdited` from a window class then you'll probably want to do:

```
class Document: NSDocument {

   var myDoc = MyDoc()

    override var isDocumentEdited: Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```